# How to show UI Tour/Guide on first visit only

Tags: javascript, laravel, user-interface, view, laravel-blade

I'm using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), but I guess this is a general UI/View question. 
I want to use a library like [Shepherd](http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/) to show a tour of the user UI. How do I implement it to show only on the first visit to the page?

Is there a better solution than creating a table that holds the `user.id` and the guides for each page? Something like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | seen_page1 | seen_page2 |
------------------------------------------
|  1 |       5 |          0 |          0 |
------------------------------------------
|  2 |       6 |          1 |          0 |
------------------------------------------
...
```

I'm just concerned with the extra query I have to make with each visit.

Comment: I would recommend a Many-to-Many relationships between users and pages, and once a user visits a specific page, a record is added to the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @MinaAbadir suggestion. Here is the guide on how to do it:

- I'm using [Laravel Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) to create my pivot table
- Run `php artisan make:migration page` and `php artisan make:migration:pivot pages users`
- Now you can do `$user->pages->contains($user);` and pass the return value to your view.
- And run `$user->pages()->attach($page);` once the guide/tour has been shown for the page

I feel like this is better than storing a whole row of `0`'s and `1`'s or storing it client side.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is an option.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('viewed')){
   tour.start();  
   localStorage.setItem('viewed','yes');
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't using localStorage mean that the Guide/Tour will display every time the user changed a browser/device?

Comment: To answer your question. Yes. Alternatively you could send new user's to a different route with the Shepherd tour. You are trying to track whether a user has seen specific pages after they log in if I understand correctly. There are other way's of designing that table, but I don't see a way around making a query for that information.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party, but I wrote a simple tutorial on how to display the tour only one time. It is inspired by @ryderpro's answer (uses `localStorage`), but it can also take into account whether the user has actually interacted with the tour or not (has finished or cancelled it): [How to Display Shepherd.js Only Once](https://yonkov.github.io/post/display-shepherd-only-once/)